# shell sed to replace a special character in a text file but unable to replace it

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I am trying to replace sam_18 with sam in a text file but it doesnt produce the correct result.

```
sed -i -e 's/sam_18/sam/g'
```

It doesnt produce any output. I am a bit confused if it is considering '_' in between as a special character. 
Any help?Thanks

Comment: That uses `-i` and so edits the file in place (assuming you gave it a filename as an argument). Run **exactly** like that that will hang waiting for data on standard input (type some lines and hit `ctrl-d` to see it do something).

Comment: With option `-i` and without a filename it should produce this output: `sed: no input files`

Comment: Which platform is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option `-i` requires a file (at least) to perform the in-place substitution:

```
sed -i -e 's/sam_18/sam/g' myfile
```

If no file are provided, `sed` reads from the standard input (or an input pipe). You cannot use `-i` in that case. You would then do something like:

```
cat myfile | sed -e 's/sam_18/sam/g' > newfile
```